# Changing a directory structure in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, directory-structure

I have a single-person single-folder mercurial repository. The directory structure is simple:

```
P104
  lecture_notes
    files under version control live here
```

After a while I realize I want to have two directories within the repository, like this

```
P104
  lecture_notes
    files under version control live here  (.hg is here)
  homework
    more files under version control
```

Now, if I'm just trying to add files to the repository, it fails:

```
br@ymir:~/P104/lecture_notes$ ll ..
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 br br 4096 2012-02-02 18:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 br br 4096 2012-02-01 20:46 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 br br 4096 2012-02-02 17:44 homework/
drwxr-xr-x 4 br br 4096 2012-02-02 18:06 lecture_notes/
br@ymir:~/P104/lecture_notes$ hg add ../homework/hw1_P104.tex 
abort: ../homework/hw1_P104.tex not under root
```

My first idea was to clone the repo one level up in the directory structure, add files to the clone, and delete the original repo. But even cloning fails:

```
br@ymir:~/P104/2011/lecture_notes$ hg clone . ..
abort: destination '..' is not empty
```

So the question is whether there's a Mercurial-ish way of doing this other than creating a clean repository somewhere else and copying files manually?

Comment: +1 - What an awesome way to learn version control. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the root directory of your Mercurial repo is under `~/P104/lecture_notes`, I would rather:

1. rename `lecture_notes` into P104
2. make a subdirectory `lecture_notes`
3. move all the existing files in that new sub-directory
4. add `homework` and its files in the renamed P104 directory
5. `hg add` everything

The idea is to keep the `.hg` repo where it is (`~/P104/lecture_notes` renamed into `~/P104/P104`) and reorganize the files within that renamed directory.
No need to clone.

Answer (score 7):

I like VonC's solution where you don't move the `.hg` folder. It's a straight forward solution. Here is an alternative where you *do* move it and so have to rename fewer folders:

1. Move the `.hg` folder up to `~/P104`

   ```
   $ mv ~/P104/lecture_notes/.hg ~/P104
   ```

   Seen from the perspective of Mercurial, you will have moved all the top-level files into a `lecture_notes` directory. There will also suddenly be new untracked files in the `homework` folder.
2. Let Mercurial figure out the renames:

   ```
   $ hg addremove
   ```

   This will correctly detect that files that were top-level files before now live in the `lecture_notes` directory. The untracked (and un-ignored) files in `homework` are just added.
3. Save the changes:

   ```
   $ hg commit
   ```

The overall "trick" is that files in the working copy are seen relative to the `.hg` directory. So by moving the `.hg` directory up in the file system hierarchy, we effectively move the working copy files down in the hierarchy inside the working copy.

Comment: thanks! Good to know about `addremove`. Next time I have this issue, will use this solution (with VonC's way I had to manually `hg add`  and `hg remove` files)