# Change root directory of repo in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm working on an Android game with the folder structure:

```
\bin
\data (contains game graphics)
\libs (libgdx engine jars)
\src
----\com
--------\brand
------------\game
                 (*.class files)
```

Foolishly, I created a mercurial repository (hg init) in the \src directory. Thus, if I update any of the graphics (small file sizes), they aren't added to the repo when I commit. My question is: how can I change the root of the repo to include the \data directory as well as the \src directory, but without including the \libs directory as that includes 10-20mb jars?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing a directory structure in Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117959/changing-a-directory-structure-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1) Start a new repo.  It's quick and easy but you'll lose your history.

2) Use hg rename.  This is effectively a move command.

Rename the src directory to be something meaningful and then do this.

1. hg rename MyProject/com MyProject/src/com
2. Copy all the files/folders into the MyProject/ directory.
3. Mark bin and libs as ignorable and
4. Add everything else.
5. hg commit

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to just do an `hg rename`, you can do it with the [convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) extension (which comes by default with Mercurial, you just need to [enable it in your `.hgrc`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Configuration)).

Run it with the [`--filemap`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) parameter and a filemap file that has something like:

```
rename com src/com
```

You will end up with a new repository with all of your history, but with your `com` directory moved into `src/com`. You can then copy you `bin`, `data` and `libs` folders in there, run `hg addremove` and you should be all good to go.

**Warning**: the new repo is completely different than the old one -- changeset IDs and such will be different, so anybody you worked with in the past will have to get on the new repo.