# hg status ignoring a new moved in directory

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've a `_project_` directory (well, it's not named *project* but never mind that, the underscored are there though) with several subdirectories and a bunch of files. Around of size of 100Mb, give or take is the size of it with the .hg repo inside.

Now, I've had another, let's call `_something_` directory with the .hg repo inside, which I've moved completely to `_project_` and ran `hg status`. Nothing showed up!

*Something* has files with dates running up 5 years behind, and some of them are older than *project* repo, but I don't think that should matter.

No .hgignore in any of these, anywhere.

Has anyone got a clue why `hg status` wouldn't show these "new" files in its subdirectory? Do the underscores in the name have anything to do with it?

...

"Nested" repos?

```
\_project_\.hg
\_project_\_something_\.hg
```

Comment: You have nested repositories. Correct?

Comment: @zerkms - You mean the above? Yup.

Comment: You cannot just nest them. Nested repositories are handled in a special way: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos

Comment: @zerkms - Ah, I see ... but apart from that special case (nested repos <- personal note: don't nest repos) hg status always shows the status of files, right? (well, that and .hgignore)

Comment: nope, it doesn't show the status for the files for the manually nested repositories. Added that as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the issue because you nested the repositories manually. It is wrong and isn't supposed to work. You won't see any files added to the nested repository while used `hg status` for outer one. Proper nesting will solve the issue.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

Comment: Thanks zerkms! I don't care about nested repos, just that status always shows me the current status of the files. It's pretty important that I don't lose any ... well, in any case, ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you nest repositories like you show with:

```
\_project_\.hg
\_project_\_something_\.hg
```

then all Mercurial commands will very carefully ignore the nested `_something_` repository.

This is done since it would be weird to track a file in `_something_` in two repositories. Also, there are many people who version control their home directory so that there is both

```
/home/mg/.hg/
```

and

```
/home/mg/src/foo/.hg/
```

The inner `foo` repository is just a clone of something I work on. Here it's really nice that `hg status` wont show files in `foo` when I'm in the root of my home directory.

Like zerkms point out, we have a feature called [subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) that let you work with nested repositories in a special way. I don't think that's what you want here, though.

I take it that you don't want to lose the history for your files in `_something_` and that you *do* want to have `_something_` inside `_project_`. If so, then you can rename the files inside `_something_` to push them one level down and then add the files from `_project_` at the top level. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140577/110204) for the details.